# Combine factors with NAs

Tags: r

I have a matrix of characters and there are numerous NAs.  I would like to create a new variable which combines all (non-NA) strings into one. So that from

```
(df = data.frame(matrix(c("A", "B", "C", NA, NA, "E", NA, "D", "A", "C", "B", "C", NA, "C", "A"), ncol = 3)))

    X1   X2   X3
1    A    E    B
2    B <NA>    C
3    C    D <NA>
4 <NA>    A    C
5 <NA>    C    A
```

then I would have

```
     X1   X2   X3 newvar
1    A    E    B  A:B:E
2    B <NA>    C   B:C
3    C    D <NA>   C:D
4 <NA>    A    C   A:C
5 <NA>    C    A   A:C
```

Notice that the individual letters alphabetize so I don't get `"A:C"` and `"C:A"` in the last two rows.

I've tried

```
within(df, newvar <- factor(X1:X2:X3))
```

which gives

```
    X1   X2   X3 newvar
1    A    E    B  A:E:B
2    B <NA>    C   <NA>
3    C    D <NA>   <NA>
4 <NA>    A    C   <NA>
5 <NA>    C    A   <NA>
```

but the presence of NAs overrides the aggregation.

Comment: Try `paste` as an alternative

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this..

```
df$newvar <- apply(df,1, function(x) paste( sort( na.omit(x) ) , collapse = ":") )
#    X1   X2   X3 newvar
#1    A    E    B  A:B:E
#2    B <NA>    C    B:C
#3    C    D <NA>    C:D
#4 <NA>    A    C    A:C
#5 <NA>    C    A    A:C
```

We `apply` a function across each row of your `data.frame` which removes NA values, sorts the remaining values and pastes them together with `":"` as a separator, assiging them to the new column `newvar` in your `data.frame`.